# How to map 9-digit ZIP (ZIP+4) codes to census tracts?

Tags: census, address, zip-codes, apportion, zip4

The U.S. Department of Housing and Development provides a [crosswalk](https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/usps_crosswalk.html) between standard 5-digit ZIP codes and census tracts. This is a hard problem, as neither set's units are contained in the others'. (And units needs not be polygons on a map either.)

However, 9-digit ZIP codes are so tiny, so precise that the mapping should be easier, only too long to publish as crosswalks. Is this a geolocation problem, then? Does any service provide an API useful for exactly this?

The United States Postal Service makes some ZIP+4 products [available](https://postalpro.usps.com/address-quality-solutions/zip-4-product), but without an easy way to map them to census tracts.

Comment: ZIP+4 codes are really linear features (describing a route or portion of a delivery route) and point features (describing an address, a post office, or a post office box).  There is no easy mapping between them, even in a many-to-many.  Best yet, both periodically change. Good luck.